# How to check if choice field is empty

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a choice field.

```
class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    entry = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__():
        ...... populated entry here
```

I want to show/hide form in template based on if there are no entries. How to check if there is no data in `{{form.entry}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can check field value in template:

```
{% if not form.entry.value %}
... show form in template ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me.

```
 {% if not form.entry.field.choices %}
....
{%endif%}
```

Better solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% ifequal form.entry.text "" %}
 #dosomething 
{% endifequal %}
```